# call a method inside of the map operator when the auth state changes

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm doing a web application in Angular 8 and [Angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire).

I'm trying to implement Firebase Authentication to log in the user and then, read its data in Firestore. Finally, save this data using a local `BehaviorSubject`.

```
import {User} from 'firebase';

export interface FirebaseUser {
  readonly uid: string;
  readonly email: string;
  readonly emailVerified: boolean;
}

export interface IUser {
  id?: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  gender: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  // To have the user's auth data from Firebase Authentication.
  private bsCurrentUserAuth: BehaviorSubject<FirebaseUser> = new BehaviorSubject<FirebaseUser>(null);
  readonly currentUserAuth$: Observable<FirebaseUser> = this.bsCurrentUserAuth.asObservable();

  // To have the user's document data.
  private bsCurrentUser: BehaviorSubject<IUser> = new BehaviorSubject<IUser>(null);
  readonly currentUser$: Observable<IUser> = this.bsCurrentUser.asObservable();

  private user$: Observable<IUser>;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
  ) {
    // Subscribe to the auth state, then get firestore user document || null
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        // Logged in
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<IUser>(`${COLLECTIONS.USERS}/${user.uid}`).snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(changes => {
                const data = changes.payload.data() as IUser;
                const id = changes.payload.id;
                const docData = {id, ...data};
                this.saveUser(user, docData); // This is not being called.
                return docData;
              }));
        } else {
          // Logged out
          this.clearAll();
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  // This is not being called.
  private saveUser(user: User, userDoc: IUser) {
    console.log('saveUser');
    this.bsCurrentUserAuth.next(user);
    this.bsCurrentUser.next(userDoc);
  }

  private clearAll() {
    this.bsCurrentUserAuth.next(null);
    this.bsCurrentUser.next(null);
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): Promise<UserCredential> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

}
```

Right now, the user can log in, but, the data I want to save in the `BehaviorSubject` is not there because for some reason, the `saveUser()` method is not being called.

The idea is:

1. Log in
2. Save the user's auth data from Firebase Authentication in the `BehaviorSubject`.
3. Save the user's document data in the `BehaviorSubject`.

My goal is to have this data available in the two `BehaviorSubject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where your actually subscribing to the user$ observable. looking at this it should work just fine assuming you have the proper imports and subscribe to user$. Login and getting the user state aren't coupled so I am guess your just missing the subscribing bit.

```
import {User} from 'firebase';

export interface FirebaseUser {
  readonly uid: string;
  readonly email: string;
  readonly emailVerified: boolean;
}

export interface IUser {
  id?: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  gender: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  // To have the user's auth data from Firebase Authentication.
  private bsCurrentUserAuth: BehaviorSubject<FirebaseUser> = new BehaviorSubject<FirebaseUser>(null);
  readonly currentUserAuth$: Observable<FirebaseUser> = this.bsCurrentUserAuth.asObservable();

  // To have the user's document data.
  private bsCurrentUser: BehaviorSubject<IUser> = new BehaviorSubject<IUser>(null);
  readonly currentUser$: Observable<IUser> = this.bsCurrentUser.asObservable();

  private user$: Observable<IUser>;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
  ) {
    // Subscribe to the auth state, then get firestore user document || null
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        // Logged in
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<IUser>(`${COLLECTIONS.USERS}/${user.uid}`).snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(changes => {
                const data = changes.payload.data() as IUser;
                const id = changes.payload.id;
                const docData = {id, ...data};
                this.saveUser(user, docData); // This is not being called.
                return docData;
              }));
        } else {
          // Logged out
          this.clearAll();
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe();
//you need to actually subscribe to the user state be sure to also unsubscribe when this is destroyed if not a singleton service
  }

  // This is not being called.
  private saveUser(user: User, userDoc: IUser) {
    console.log('saveUser');
    this.bsCurrentUserAuth.next(user);
    this.bsCurrentUser.next(userDoc);
  }

  private clearAll() {
    this.bsCurrentUserAuth.next(null);
    this.bsCurrentUser.next(null);
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): Promise<UserCredential> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why I need to subscribe? I thought that the read of te document will be done with the return of the `this.afs.doc(...)`. If I don't subscribe, what is being saved in the Observable is just the reference of the document? I don't get the logic...

Comment: before you subscribe all your doing is creating an observable. which could be subscribed to somewhere else. But until you actually subscribe to it it doesn't execute. this.afs.doc(...) is never happening becasue the observable doesnt ever have anything observing it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I have noticed that my IDE is giving me an error in `this.user$` that says "Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable ': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.". Any idea why this error is present?